# How to find the geolocation of an android user from webpage

Tags: android, web, geolocation

I am developing a webpage which requires the userlocation for loading some data. The web page is mainly intended for android users. I need to find the geo location of the user when the user opens that page? How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If aviable, the JavaScript geolocation object will provide you with that data.

For the concrete implementation, have a look at this question: [Which Devices Support Javascript Geolocation via navigator.geolocation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349064/which-devices-support-javascript-geolocation-via-navigator-geolocation)

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 has a geolocation facility. Android 2.x devices should support it.

For Android 1.x devices, try the Google Gears equivalent.