# Location Specific Content

Tags: geolocation, location

I would like the content in my website to change depending from where the request is coming(location). Would it be a nice idea to do it based on the IP Address? Is there any other way to do it?

Thanks :)

Comment: Probably best to treat IP Geoloc as a good suggested default location than the *true* location.  

'Net Point-of-Presence can often be tens/hundreds/thousands of miles from actual user location e.g. corporate proxies, mobile devices etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a number of options available for the handling of location. There's the [W3C Geo API](http://www.wait-till-i.com/2010/01/25/finding-the-current-location-by-ip-and-with-the-w3c-geo-api/)([*discussion of browser support here*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349064/which-devices-support-javascript-geolocation-via-navigator-geolocation)),there's an example [here](http://www.thewhyandthehow.com/javascript-geolocation-using-google-ajax-apis/) using the Google AJAX API,. An overview of a number of options and their relative benefits is [here](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/03/08/entering-the-wonderful-world-of-geo-location/)