# Calculate the current location longitude and latitude

Tags: javascript, python, django, view

I have a hard-coded address for particular place but i want to calculate current location longitude and latitude (using jquery or python script). This is my Django view at the moment:

```
def maps(request):
    school = School.objects.get(id=1)
    dictte={'latitude':school.latitute,'longitude':school.longitude}
    print dictte
    print dictte.keys()
    print dictte['latitude'],'-----'
    school_latitute = float(dictte['latitude'])
    print school_latitute,'raj'
    print dictte['longitude'],'===='
    school_longtitude = float(dictte['longitude'])
    print school
    api_key="aa"
    gmaps = GoogleMaps(api_key)
    address = 'Veerannapalya,Bangalore,Karnataka, India - 560043'
    lat, lng = gmaps.address_to_latlng(address)
    print lat, lng

    if lat == school_latitute and lng == school_longtitude:

        schoo = {'Name of the school':school.name, 'address':school.address.address}
        strf= str(schoo)
        print strf

        return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(strf),content_type = 'application/json; charset=utf8')
    else:
        print 'nothing'    
    return render_to_response('staff.html',{'lat':lat,'lng':lng},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

As you can see, the address is currently hardcoded in the line:

`address = 'Veerannapalya,Bangalore,Karnataka, India - 560043'`

Then, from this, I obtain the latitude/longitude. What I'd like to do is rather obtain the current location of the user in the browser, and then use this latitude/longitude.

Comment: You need to clarify your question a little bit more. I'm not sure what you're asking. All I see is code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [W3 geolocation API](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html) to do this client-side in JavaScript.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  function(pos){
    var lat = pos.coords.latitude;
    var long = pos.coords.longitude;
    // send coordinates to server, or display on map, if you wish
  },
  function(){
    /* Handler if location could not be found */
  }
);
```

It's not an official specification yet, but it does work on most PC browsers and some phone browsers. Here's a list of [devices where it does work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349064/which-devices-support-javascript-geolocation-via-navigator-geolocation).