# How do I call Webshims navigation.geolocation directly

Tags: html, geolocation

I'm using HTML5 navigator.geolocation in my web application, with a Webshims fallback when the browser doesn't natively support it. However, I found that a number of browsers have broken implementations of HTML5 navigator.geolocation.

How can I call the Webshims geolocation directly after I find out that a browser that advertises itself as supporting navigator.geolocation, does in fact not?

I can't call this:
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition 
because the it hasn't been polyfill-ed, the browser thinks it can support navigator.geolocation.

I'm looking for something like webshims.geolocation.getCurrentPosition.

Comment: How do you detect, that the browser doesn't support geolocation? Wich browser are you talking about???

Comment: Two examples of why this would happen:  https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=41001, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9215662/navigator-geolocation-getcurrentposition-callbacks-wont-work-on-firefox-10. In those cases I would like to fall back on the Webshims geolocation.